# if Dropdownlist SelectedIndex = 0 then not add any row in SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dropdown, listitem

my logic is that if ddlCoffee.SelectedIndex = 0 it will not add any row in my database. I did tried **sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", ((object)ddlCoffee.SelectedIndex) ?? DBNull.Value);** but in SQL it come out as **Qty 0** value row in SQL database which I do not want. I do not want to add any row if Qty is 0. Kindly advise how should I do?

.aspx.cs

```
      protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = "Data Source";
        string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO tbDrinks ( DrinkName, DateOfOrder, Qty, UserName, UserCompany) " +
            "values(@DrinkName, @DateOfOrder, @Qty, @UserName, @UserCompany)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
            {

                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrinkName", lblCoffee.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfOrder", DateTime.Today);

                if (ddlCoffee.SelectedIndex != 0)
                {
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", ddlCoffee.SelectedValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    //sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", ((object)ddlCoffee.SelectedIndex) ?? DBNull.Value);
                    //Will Not Add in SQL Database
                }

                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserCompany", txtCompanyName.Text);
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
             }
           }
```

.aspx

```
<table id="tbHotDrinks" class="auto-style3" border="1" bordercolor="#1FC3F3" runat="server">

    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCoffee" runat="server" Text="Coffee"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style2">
            <asp:Image ID="coffee" runat="server" Height="76px" ImageUrl="~/images/coffee.gif" Width="99px" ImageAlign="TextTop" />
        </td>

        <td class="auto-style11">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCoffee" runat="server">
               <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select Qty--</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>                        
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you can check what value got insert if you choose different dropdown item, if it is expected the you can follow my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only conditional you have set is

```
  if (ddlCoffee.SelectedIndex != 0)
  {
       sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", ddlCoffee.SelectedValue);
  }
```

Nothing is stopping this line from executing

```
 sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You need to wrap the whole event in a conditional so that the sqlcmd is never executed e.g.:

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
 {
      if (ddlCoffee.SelectedIndex != 0)
      {
           conn.Open();
           using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
           {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrinkName", lblCoffee.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfOrder", DateTime.Today);

                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", ddlCoffee.SelectedValue);

                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserCompany", txtCompanyName.Text);
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
      }
 }
```

Note, a better way to handle this is to have some client side validation so that the form is never submitted in the first place if the quantity isn't chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to think about your SelectedIndex rather SelectedValue. Try this following code hope it solve your problem

```
if (ddlCoffee.SelectedValue != 0)
{
     sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", ddlCoffee.SelectedValue);
}
```